# R Program on ec2 seems to be slow?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Here is the output I get after running an input file through R. It is running on EC2 ubuntu instance with about 8gb RAM and 2 CPUs. I looked in the monitor and when the R program runs, it only uses about 20% of the CPU.

> proc.time()-t1
>      user  system elapsed 
>     0.584   0.320   0.902
>
> proc.time()
>      user  system elapsed 
>     6.780   1.132   7.902

That SAME input file on my local machine is done in about 1.5 seconds. The hardware is about the same. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could be all sorts of issues. Different CPUs? Lots of I/O? You haven't told us anything about what the script actually does.

Comment: There's not a lot of I/O on the server. Are there any good benchmarking things I could setup to see what's going on? fyi, it's an m1.large ec2 instance and all I know about the cpu is it's in the Intel Xeon Family. The local machine cpu is intel i5-2300 @ 2.8GHz

Comment: With the exception of the largest instances, you will not get full CPU power allocated to your instance. How are you determining how much CPU is being used (Some tools wont report the correct number due to the virtual environment)?

Comment: I'm using Amazon's cloudwatch to do the monitoring.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to do when you're experiencing performance problems with a single instance is to reboot.  If the host is busy, a reboot will generally move it to another host with more availability.

If that doesn't help, the next thing is to find out what is limiting you.  The cloudwatch metrics are OK, but probably not detailed enought. You can turn on detailed monitoring which might help, or there are a number of monitoring tools that can help. NewRelic offers server monitoring free, CopperEgg has a 1 user dev license free, and there are probably dozens of others that will give you a bit more information via a free trial.

All right, lets assume you know what the problem is.

If it's I/O, there are a couple of solutions.  You can try using ephemeral storage - this is usually attached to the instance, so will probably be faster than EBS-backed storage.  The drawback is that when the instance is shut down, you lose everything in ephemeral storage, so make sure that you save off any results.  For more I/O, you can use provisioned IOPS in EBS, or move to an instance that offers local SSD storage.

If it's CPU, are you using both cores?  Are you seeing a high "stolen" percentage?  If so, you might want to move to an instance with better CPU - there are Cxx type instances which might be better than a general purpose M1 or M3 type instance.